# How to convert tif to dep extension?

Tags: grass-gis, data, whitebox-gat

In white box when i try to import or do any processes it's asking .dep extension
How can i convert .tif into .dep extension??

If try to pass LISS3 data in GRASS GIS it is taking as single bands. So i stacked the LISS3 bands as image then I passed . After that also its taking single band data as input.
When I tried with LANDSAT data it's giving dispaly map but its not performing processes on that data...
provide any recommended sample data to GRASS GIS and Whitebox soatial analysis tool...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what kind of TIF format a LISS3 image is, but I will assume that it is a geoTIFF as this is the case for most satellite data. Whitebox GAT can import uncompressed, single band GeoTIFF images simply by selecting them from the list of available files when you press 'Add Layer'. You can open multiple images at a time as well:

[image]

Whitebox will automatically convert the TIFF image into its own native raster format (.dep header with .tas binary data) but will issue a warning so the user knows what is about to happen:

[image]

You can just dismiss that warning. When the image is first displayed, you may find that it doesn't look quite right because it will default the display minimum and maximum values to that of the image min and max, which may not be very appropriate. You can change the display minimum and maximum values in the Layer Properties dialog:

[image]

(Clipping them by a specified percent is quite effective) and it will re-stretch the palette. You may also want to update the image NoData value (under the File tab of the Layer's Display Properties).

[image]

Alternatively, you can improve your image using any of the several image stretches available within the Image Processing Tools => Image Enhancement toolbox. There is also a tutorial in the Help called 'How To Get Data Into Whitebox' that might be of help.

Please note that I am the lead developer of the Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools project.

Comment: I want source code of whitebox

Comment: We are developing website which will use GIS application services.... If I want to use ms-dos cmd prompt insted of white box's scripting tool ...Is it possible sir

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/source/checkout How can I use this to my perpose

Comment: @user28536 If you look in the Help menu of Whitebox, you'll see a list of tutorial topics. The first one is called 'How to get the Whitebox sourcecode" It'll walk you through the process of downloading and working with the Whitebox source code. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @user28536 I'm sorry but at the moment, you can only perform Whitebox scripting within the in-GUI scripting environment. Whitebox does not currently support scripting from a DOS command prompt. Perhaps some time in the future this can be added.

Comment: would you please let me know that is there any other softwares will support scripting from a DOS command prompt